# Change culture in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm using URL based localization logic in my MVC app. 
so, default route would be mysite/someControler, and localized route would be mysite/en-US/someControler.

"en-US" is value for "culture" parameter which has default value.

I'm wondering what is there any generic way to switch between cultures, and keep all the url route values and parameters?

Thanks

Comment: http://adamyan.blogspot.com/2010/02/aspnet-mvc-2-localization-complete.html

Answer (score 0):

I do something simple:
In my base controller (all other controllers inherits from it) I set the following ViewData bits:

```
    If Request.Path.Contains("/en/") Then
        ViewData("PathEs") = Request.Path.Replace("/en/", "/es/")
        ViewData("PathPt") = Request.Path.Replace("/en/", "/pt/")
    ElseIf Request.Path.Contains("/pt/") Then
        ViewData("PathEn") = Request.Path.Replace("/pt/", "/en/")
        ViewData("PathEs") = Request.Path.Replace("/pt/", "/es/")
    Else
        ViewData("PathEn") = Request.Path.Replace("/es/", "/en/")
        ViewData("PathPt") = Request.Path.Replace("/es/", "/pt/")
    End If
```

And then in the Master Page

```
 <div id="langbar">
    <% if not string.isnullorempty(ViewData("PathEs")) then %>
       <a href="<%= ViewData("PathEs") %>">Español</a>
    <% end  if %>
    <% if not string.isnullorempty(ViewData("PathEn")) then %>
       <a href="<%= ViewData("PathEn") %>">English</a>
    <% end  if %>
    <% if not string.isnullorempty(ViewData("PathPt")) then %>
       <a href="<%= ViewData("PathPt") %>">Portugues</a>
    <% end  if %>
</div>
```

Not too smart, but get the job done well if your are dealing with few langs (you sure can optimize both rutines)